# Countdown + break in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I am trying to make a timer in Bash which countdowns 20 minutes and then starts a 10 minute break immediately after the previous. Then the loop 
continues and returns again to 20 minutes.

```
#!/bin/bash
MIN=20
BREAK=10
while [[ 0 -ne $MIN ]]; do
    echo "$MIN"
    sleep 1
    MIN=$[$MIN-1]
done
WHILE [[ 0 -ne $BREAK ]]; do
    echo "$BREAK"
    sleep 1
    BREAK=$[$BREAK-1]
done
```

I made it with seconds here. So 20 seconds pass by and then the 10 seconds start immediately. But when the 10 seconds expire the script stops. Is there a way to start again with 20 minutes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, to repeat a block of code you use a `while do ... done` loop. So to start all over again you just need to wrap the entire segment of code in another `while...` loop.

This time the condition can be just the command `true`. So you'd get this:

```
while true
do
    # Put the code to be repeated forever in here
    :
done
```

Comment: I was close to solving it but I was missing something. Thank you!